# Saving a canvas to a PNG or JPEG file

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I'm currently programming a webstie where the users can Upload .mp4 videos. I would like to make a thumbnail when the user uploads his video and write this image to a .jpg or .png file on my server.

The problem that I encounter is that the file is stored on my server but it isn't viewed/ seen as an image file.

This is my code for the moment.

The HTML part

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<video id="v" controls>
  <source src="/215003/1.1/videos/7/f9ed57e2b0ee1e87a4cbc17c7b743eff.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The javascript part where I process the canvas etc.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
var v = document.getElementById('v');
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var v = document.getElementById("v");

v.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
 this.currentTime = this.duration / 2;
  }, false);

v.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", function (e) {
 var cw = this.videoWidth,
     ch = this.videoHeight;
     console.log(cw);
     console.log(ch);
     canvas.width = cw;
     canvas.height = ch;
     draw(this,context,cw,ch);
     var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'saveThumb.php',
      data: 'img=' + dataURL
    }).done(function(o) {
        console.log(dataURL);
      console.log('saved'); 
    });
 }, false );
},false);
function draw(v,c,w,h) {
  c.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
  setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,w,h);
}
```

The PHP file to process the data and store the image :

```
<?php
// requires php5
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'img/');
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

Somebody that can help me out ? :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and check your console.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try this? Can you view the image file through FTP or other means, or does the file just not exist correctly as an image file?

Comment: Hi Jake, I don't get any error when I execute the program. I can see the file and the size of it on the FTP server. But when I open it with windows, it says the file isn't recognized. This is the data I get from the 'canvas.toDataURL('image/png');'

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAFoCAYAAADHMkpRAAASdklEQVR4Xu3WQQEAAAgCMelf2iA3GzB8sHMECBAgQIAAAQIpgaXSCk(and a lot more characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my error. The problem was that the draw funcation had a SetTimeOut function. So I was only writing a black image to my server because the DataToURL function triggered to fast.

The Solution is to put everything after the draw function in a write function. and give that function a timeOut to be sure an image is drawn.

Here is the corrected code :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 var v = document.getElementById('v');
 var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

 var v = document.getElementById("v");
v.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
 this.currentTime = this.duration / 3;
 }, false);
v.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", function () {
 var cw = this.videoWidth;
 var ch = this.videoHeight;
    console.log(cw); //displaying the width of the video
    console.log(ch); //displaying the height of the video
    canvas.width = cw; //seting the width of the canvas
    canvas.height = ch; //setting the height of the canvas
    draw(this,context,cw,ch); // Drawing the image from the video onto the canvas
    setTimeout(function() {
    write(canvas);
    }, 1000)
    }, false );

},false);

function draw(v,c,w,h) {
 c.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
 setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,w,h);
}
function write(c) {
 var dataURL = c.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
 var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src=dataURL;
    document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(image);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'saveThumb.php',
      data: 'img=' + dataURL
    }).done(function(o) {
        console.log(dataURL);
      console.log('saved'); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I seldom ever use PHP but I do know that Base64 encoding does not have any spaces in it. Not that it would change anything because there are no spaces, but why the second replace space with plus?

As to your problem. You need to change the event you are using to trigger the post. `onloadedmetadata` is fired before there is any data to render a frame. You should be using the `oncanplay` then you will have data to send, though as it is you should at least be getting a blank image. To see what you have on the client add 'image = new Image(); image.src=dataURL;' then add that image to the dom and you can see if you have got what you wanted rather than guessing.

Apart from that I can't find anything.

Comment: Hi Blindman67, When i changed the 'onloadedmetadata' to 'oncanplay' or 'canplay' the program went into a loop that didn't end. So I changed my can play to 'onloadedmetadata'
I added the lines you suggested to show the image and now I see that the Base64 enconding just gives me a blank image for PNG and a black image for Jpeg... I think there has to be a problem with the encoding in the javascript I think

Comment: The program goes into a loop because the draw function calls its self with settimeout. Change back to oncanplay and remover the set timeout.